# Using jQuery UI .position on img with width: auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I'm building a very simple gallery. When clicking a thumbnail image, a fullsized image should pop up fixed in the center of the window, with a surrounding div to make it modal.

I'm struggling to make jQuery's .position method work. If I set a pixel height and width for the image, it works fine. However, if I set a pixel height and width: auto, the image isn't centered as it should. I think centering in this case is done based on zero width.

```
$(document).on("click", ".galleri", function() {      
    if ($("#imgFullWindow").length === 0){
        $("body").append("<div id='imgFullWindow'></div>");
    }

    $("#imgFullWindow").css({
        display  : "none",
        position : "absolute",
        "z-index": "5",
        top      : "0px",
        left     : "0px",
        width    : $(document).width(),
        height   : $(document).height(),
        background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
    }).append("<img />");

    $("#imgFullWindow img").attr("src", $(this)[0].src).css({
        height   : "150px",
        width    : "120px", //This works
        //width    : "auto", //This doesn't  
        position : "fixed"
    }).position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center center+40",
        of:$(window),
        collision: "none"
    });

    $("#imgFullWindow").fadeIn(500);
});
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/apAu3/ Try commenting line 19 and uncomment line 20 to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug that makes positioning fail with width:"auto", but I found a way by calculating the aspect ratio in advance to calculate a pixel width.

```
    //Find the image aspect ratio
    var imgRatio = ($(this).height()/$(this).width())
```

Then in the .css method:

```
    height   : $(window).height(),
    width    : ($(window).height() / imgRatio), //This works
```

New jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/K3ubS/

Answer (score 1):

I kind of redid the code a little bit, here on this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apAu3/1/) (you'll have to fit it to your needs):

HTML:

```
<div>I'm the image container. Click the image!
    <img class='galleri' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/LightningMcQueen.jpg' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.galleri {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width : "auto";
}

.big-image {
    /*perfect horizontal and vertical positioning*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    /*in order for this perfect positioning to work,
      the element needs a declared width OR height,
      along with margin: auto*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 150px;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('img.galleri').on('click',function() {

    var box = $('.box') || null;

    if($('.box').length < 1) {
        var bigImage = $(this).clone();
        $('body').append('<div class="box"></div>');
        $('.box').fadeIn().append(bigImage);
        bigImage.addClass('big-image');
    }

});

$('body').on('click','.box',function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

Also, check out [this Smashing Magazine article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) about perfect horizontal and verticle positioning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm a fan of the .position method and would like to use it wherever I can. I found a hack myself (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer to your question yet, but out of curiosity, why not use one of the very useful lightbox galleries out there?  
1. http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/
2. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be anything fancy, and I've already got the functionality I want - except for the broken positioning.